# How to hide copy process of Visio to RichTexbox

Tags: c#, .net, ms-office, visio

all. I've created a project that displays contents from a Visio document by copying the content and pasting the content as an image on a rich textbox in a C# winform. The problem is that when the copying process begins, Visio opens up for a few seconds and then my program copies the content. While I do want that to happen, I do not want Visio visible during the process. Is there a way to accomplice what is done while hiding Visio?

Here's the code:

```
public partial class FrmVisio : Form
{
    public FrmVisio()
    {
        InitializeComponent();         
    }

    private void cboContent_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void FrmVisio_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cboContent.Items.Add("PFD-001_Control of Documented Information Process _(R4)");
        cboContent.Items.Add("PFD-002_Management_Review_Process_(R1)");
        cboContent.Items.Add("PFD-003 Control of Non-conformance Process Flow(R1)");
        cboContent.Items.Add("PFD-004_Internal Audit Process _(R1)");
        cboContent.Items.Add("PFD-008_Risk & Opportunity Process _(R1)");
        cboContent.Items.Add("PFD-010_Change_Control_Process_Flow_Diagram_(R1)");
        cboContent.Items.Add("PFD-011_Determine_Requirements_for_Products_Services_(R2)");
    }

    private void btnOpenWord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cboContent.SelectedItem == null)
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a document", "No Document Selected", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        else
        {
            var item = cboContent.SelectedItem.ToString();

            MessageBox.Show("IMPORTANT! PLEASE READ: MS Visio allows you to create shapes and diagrams. However, those things, if edited, will not be saved on the " +
                "QMS unless you export the allocated document as a PDF in the same folder and overwrite the default PDF given. DO NOT CHANGE THE FILE NAMES OR THEIR LOCATIONS! Otherwise, the link to the documents and the QMS will be broken", "PLEASE READ!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

            Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\IMS Global\Quality Management System Application\QMS\QMS\QMS\" + item + @".vsd");   
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Show the preview of the Visio Document
    /// </summary>
    public void DisplayVsio()
    {
        //TODO: Find Better Alternative to Show Visio Documentation.
        //TODO: If not possible, edit widgets in windows form.
        if(cboContent.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a document", "No Document Selected", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);               
        }
        else
        {
            var item = cboContent.SelectedItem.ToString();
            Visio.Application appObject = new Visio.Application();

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Document doc = appObject.Documents.Open(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\IMS Global\Quality Management System Application\QMS\QMS\QMS\" + item + @".vsd");
            doc.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.SelectAll();
            doc.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
            richTextBox1.Paste();

            appObject.Quit();
        }
    }

    private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Clear();
        DisplayVsio();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

Visio.Application appObject = new Visio.Application();

to:

Visio.Application appObject = new Visio.InvisibleApp();